# session for sub-domain.example.com using PHP

Tags: php, session, cookies, subdomain

I have setup .htaccess to redirect me.example.com to example.com/fun/index.php.  This index.php has a session.  When a user is on me.example.com/index.php the session is never enabled, but is enabled on example.com/fun/index.php.

How do I enable session on me.example.com/index.php path.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ini_set('session.cookie_domain', '.example.com' );
```

Comment: Don't forget to add session_start(); at the head of the page , and try to replace the string .example with your sub domain

Comment: Have a look here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4631803/php-multi-domain-sessions-ini-set-not-working

Answer (score 1):

```
session_set_cookie_params(3600, '/', '.example.com');
session_start();
```