# Login.php on https include on http page

Tags: php, ssl, authentication

I just changed my account functions on my website to SSL.

The http website has been split now between the normal http website and https is on a subdomain called ssl.website.

With http only on my website the PHP script that I used was showing the account links and options after logging in by using a php session. Now it only shows that on ssl.website and when I go to http the login screen changes to logging in option even when they are still logged in on https.

See my PHP code below.

How can I fix this. Is there a possibility to include the https login.php file on all http pages, so it reads the session after loggin in? Or how should I fix this? I tried Google, but there arený any hits that show the same problem as I have.

```
    <div id="right_column">
    <?php if(!isset($session_account)){ ?>
        <div id="accountcolumn">
        <ul>
        <li>
        <h3>Account</h3>
        <form method="post" action="https://ssl.website.com/login">
        <table>
                    <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
                    <tr>
        <td>E-mail:</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td><input type="text" name="email" style="width:140px"/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td>Password:</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td><input type="password" name="password" style="width:140px" /></td>
        </tr>
                    <tr>
        <td><input type="submit" name="login" value="Login" /></td>
        </tr>
        </table>
                </form>
                </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <?php }else{ ?> 
    <div id="accountcolumn_login">
        <ul>
        <li>
        <h3>Account</h3>
        <form method="post" action="<?= $config['url']; ?>client/login">            
        <ul>
                    <li><a href="https://ssl.website.com/overview">Overview</a></li>
                <li><a href="https://ssl.website.com/shoppingbasket">Change account</a></li>
    <li><a href="https://ssl.website.com/password">Change password</a></li>
                </ul>
        </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You either have to use cookies, or make your PHP-SESSION "spread" to the subdomains like so:

php.ini:

```
session.cookie_domain = ".website.com"
```

PHP:

```
ini_set('session.cookie_domain', '.website.com' );
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Is this also possible when I use a different user for the subdomain? I created a new and other user for ssl.website.com and added that subdomain as a domain. So website.com has a different user then ssl.website.com. So two users (one with domain, other with the subdomain).

Comment: Should I follow this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4631803/php-multi-domain-sessions-ini-set-not-working